# How to make users table common for different type of users? else do i need to change User registration table based on users in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, authentication, database-design, authorization

Guys iam working with an online quiz examination  project.
i have a small doubt. basically user table is for registering users.

in my application iam the organization. my team has more than 5 users with different roles. I know about roles and permissions. our role is to upload questions in the db.

so lots of school will register and the staff memebers and students in the school are users of my application.

the role of staff is to create assessment by choosing the questions which is already stored in db.

after creating assessment student are requested to login and then write the exam. then results are verified.

Here my doubt is

as a oraganization iam also user here, the students and staff members of different schools also user here.

then how my user table must be changed.

this my structure

As my organization i will get

```
name
user_name
email
phno
password
```

these data are enough for my team. but when it comes to school say for example

`AAA matriculation Higher Secondary school` is registering to our application so i need to get the school info like school name, school address, school phno etc.

then i should register the student and staff members of that school
like

Staff A belongs to this school with this username and this password with this role with this subject ( so that when the staff login he/she can see only maths questions)

Student B belongs to this school with this username and this password with this role and this class(then only those class assessments will be shown to him/her)

so my 
`schoolDetails Table`

```
id  name         address     phno
1   School1     Address1    123
2   School2     Address2    321
3   School3     Address3    547
.
.
so on
```

when registering staff or student of that school

```
id  school_id   name    username    email   password    phno
1       1       A       AAA          a@gm   **          122
2       1       B       BBB         b@gm    **          789
```

so if i i have a user table like above then  how i can register my team??

overal my doubt is how to register my team, and other school in users table

i know that i will have a class table and subject table which will be linked to user table so based on the staff or student login that changes the display screen.

My major doubt how can i register myself and them??

Comment: I think it's better to have a pivot table for your clients like `school_users` table so you can store `user_id` and `school_id` there, you mustn't store the `school_id` in `users` table, so you can register your own team in `school_user` too

Answer (score 0):

I would split it a bit differently.
Schools, ok
User: defines users only, without any links to schools, yet
User type: defines types that each user can have
Register: links schools and users

So if your user is strictly an administrator, and not a student, you ommit that user from the register table.  This way you can even have a student take classes in two schools (if that is possible with your logic).  At least is decouples schools and users (and is good for normalization anyway).

As a general rule, defines what objects you have in your requirements.  Each of those become one table.  Then list your relations.  Single (1-1) relations become foreign keys, (many-many, 1-many) become link tables.

Tables...

```
Schools
    ID  NAME    ADDRESS     PHONE
    1   School1 Address1    514-123-1324
    2   School2 Address2    514-123-1234
    ...

User
    ID  TYPE    NAME    USERNAME    PASSWORD    PHONE
    1   1       AAA     usera       passa       514-123-1234
    2   2       BBB     userb       passb       514-123-1234
    ...

User Type
    ID  TYPE
    1   Admin
    2   Student
    ...

Register
    ID  SCHOOLID    USERID  
    1   1           1
    2   1           2
    ...
```